# Decorate an anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

So I tried this:

```
static void Main() {
    var anonymous = new { Key = "Key", Value = "Value" };

    AssemblyBuilder builder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName( "MineAsm"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder modBuilder = builder.DefineDynamicModule("MineModule");
    TypeBuilder mineType = modBuilder.DefineType("MineType", TypeAttributes.Public, anonymous.GetType());

    Type definedType = mineType.CreateType();
    Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(definedType);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in definedType.GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(instance));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But I get an exception essentially saying that anonymous types are sealed. Awesome. What I'm experimenting with is the ability to wrap an anonymous type with properties that identify when a value has changed. I know that anonymous types themselves can't be modified, but it would be nice to be able to somehow decorate it such that the compiler is nice enough to generate the base structure from a `new { }` statement, but then I run with it and make it more generally useful (for example make the properties monitorable like an ORM of sorts), yet the compiler still understands the structure and thus is able to provide intellisense.

Is this possible though, even if not using the path I'm currently following?

Comment: Since anonymous types are immutable, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Use the compiler-assist/intellisense that anonymous types provide, but then subclass it to make the object editable, where said edits can be monitored. Experimenting with an ORM idea.

Comment: As you've already discovered, that is impossible. You can surely generate a mutable object at runtime using an anonymous type as a template, but you could only use reflection to access it, since no code that the compiler has access to would know about it. Have you looked at T4 templates instead?

Comment: `no code that the compiler has access to would know about it`. Crap, that's right. Thanks

Comment: @sircodesalot, I'd abandon the notion of using anonymous types for this.  However, you could in principle use normal classes and use virtual (auto) properties that your (generated) subclasses then override.  I've tinkered with that sort of approach before and it would work fine, though you still run into painpoints as you can't new-up using the `new` operator.

Comment: It really seems like your going through more trouble than it would take to just create a "real" type.

Comment: Not really, I'd like to just add features to an anonymous type. Since it can't be done though, c'est la vie.